# How to find out 70% mid blue (#686e9f)

Tags: colors

My company launched a new branding. I'm creating palettes to rework on numerous websites. One of the colors is named Mid blue (#686E9F) and an associated color is Mid Blue Tint as 70% Mid blue but no RGB/Hex values.

How to find out 70% mid blue (#686e9f)?

Reference:
[image: Colors]

Comment: It depends entirely on what they mean by 70%. 70% what? Opacity? Brightness? Saturation? We can't tell you.

Comment: I mentioned "tint"

Comment: @HassanGulzar SO is my answer was helpful ? Did you managed to get your color ?

Comment: @GrecoJonathan Nope. I have not found the color still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact you can find it by using the opacity.

Your blue "tint" is the same as your `#686e9f` wich means this rgba representation rgba(104,110,159). And with 0.70 **opacity** on this you get back your color.

to test you can paste this `rgba(104,110,159,0.7)` on this website :

http://www.menucool.com/rgba-color-picker

Comment: This was the correct color after all: rgba(104,110,159,0.7). Thank you

Comment: Haha :) sure it was !! Glad you found it

Comment: Searching around a bit, I found this article: https://css-tricks.com/8-digit-hex-codes/ . So the hex code now becomes `686E9FB3`

Answer (score 0):

So you could begin to translate the hex-number into RGB values 
-> https://www.rgbtohex.net/hextorgb/
Then I presume you could multiply those values with 0.7, if I understand this 70% stuff correctly.

Answer (score -1):

If I understood your question correctly and you were asking for a RGB representation:

```
rgb(104, 110, 159)

68 -> 104
6e -> 110
9f -> 159
```

The hex value is just a RGB value in hexadecimal. IF you were looking for something else, please specify a clear question.